# Observing glitches and some problem when using transforms ( rotate and translate ) in css

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie in web development . I have come up with a design , a card , which on hover , rotates and shows the back of the card. I have tried using transitions and transforms (rotate , translate). I observe some glitches when using transforms , especially using rotate. This problem occurred on both chrome and safari.

This is my code :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 3s;
  background-color: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card:hover .card__content {
  transform: rotateY(.5turn);
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card__title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.card__back {
  background-color: teal;
  transform: rotateY(.5turn);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__content">
    <div class="card__front">
      <h1 class="card__title">CORONA</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <p class="card__description">FEVER
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So could anyone help me out by finding errors associated with the above code that causes this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: What **specifically** is the problem?

Comment: What is the glitch?

Comment: I am facing some issues when using transforms and is causing glitches on the screen when applying that effect . The glitch is that the text is not behaving as it is supposed to . It is appearing and disappearing which must not happen . So I just wanted to know if there is any issue with the above code that is causing the problem or if it is due to any other factors that is causing it

Comment: What is meant by glitches. Be specific.

Comment: the code above shown is basically a card which on hovering shows the back of it . The glitch problem is when I hover over the card the background color of the front changes to teal which is supposed to be the color of the back of the card while the front is pink. Also the text that is to be displayed on the back appears and disappears .